# Return SCOPE IDENTITY

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, t-sql

I'm trying to return the `SCOPE IDENTITY` of the inserted record in my stored procedure `@temp_id`, but how can I bind it to a label e.g

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxLabel_RequestTemp" Name="temp" 
PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
```

its not working

Thanks

Comment: How are you invoking the stored procedure - what means are you using for data retrieval?  Also, how are you 'returning' SCOPE_IDENTITY() from the sproc?

Comment: sqldatasource.Insert()

select @temp=CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)
return @temp
RETURN

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the Inserted event in your code and then acquire the ReturnValue parameter - as in the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.aspx).